# Is there a way to make setState synchronous to solve render issue?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state

I'm facing a problem. I just found out that setState is asynchronous.
I'm rendering a component in my render method if a certain condition is true.

Reder():

```js
render() {
        const { isFetchingSubject, isFetchingTemplate } = this.props;
        return (
            ...
                            {this.state.showLabelDetails && <Details template={this.props.match.params.templatename} close={this.toggleShowLabelDetails} data={this.state.labelDetails} />}
            ...
        );
    }
```

Function Call at onclick button:

```js
toggleShowLabelDetails = (event) => {
        if (!this.state.showLabelDetails) this.setState({ labelDetails: JSON.parse(event.target.value) })
        this.setState({ showLabelDetails: !this.state.showLabelDetails });
        if (this.state.showLabelDetails) this.setState({ labelDetails: {} })
    }
```

state:

```html
state = { 
        showLabelDetails: false,
        labelDetails: {},
     }
```

Explaination of what code is doing:

- When user hits button X it calls the function toggleShowLabelDetails()
- It changes the boolean value in the state to true and adds the value from the button the the state labelDetails which is an object.
- State changes which means component will render again and when the condition is true it will show up a new component on the screen.

50% of the times it's working well, but sometimes i'm getting the following error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token u in JSON at position 0
at Object.parse (<anonymous>)

Uncaught Error: A cross-origin error was thrown. React doesn't have access to the actual error object in development.
```

Any solution for this?

Comment: what do you intend to achieve with  this snippet  {this.state.showLabelDetails && <Details template={this.props.match.params.templatename} close={this.toggleShowLabelDetails} data={this.state.labelDetails} />}

Comment: why are you parsing the value in X label when clicked?

Comment: cross-origin error  nothing do with react render. Mostly probably in Details component your trying to fetch data from REST API. If REST API doesn't support or Rest API unable to handle request you will get cross-origin error

Answer (score 1):

Can you try doing something like this:

```
class MyComponent extends Component {

function setStateSynchronous(stateUpdate) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        this.setState(stateUpdate, () => resolve());
    });
}

async function foo() {
    // state.count has value of 0
    await setStateSynchronous(state => ({count: state.count+1}));
    // execution will only resume here once state has been applied
    console.log(this.state.count);  // output will be 1
}
```

}

Comment: Technically speaking this is still asynchronous. It's just converted from callback based to promise based

Answer (score 1):

You can pass a callback to setState.

```
this.setState(
    (state, props) => ({showLabelDetails : !state.showLabelDetails}),
    () => { // Executed when state has been updated
        // Do stuff with new state
        if (this.state.showLabelDetails) {
            this.setState({ labelDetails: {} })
        }
    }
)
```

And BTW: You cannot rely on this.state inside setState (mentionned in the react docs), since react may batch the state updates.

Comment: With your example i'm getting the following compile error: Expected an assignment or function call and instead saw an expression  no-unused-expressions

Comment: Sorry has been some months since I last used React, fixed it now :)